# PHP file_get_contents(): No Such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql

I have a class that create databases and tables in it automatically(if no database exist). The class is working fine whenever I run it directly in my localhost but if I call it from another file it is returning an error. The database creation class

```
class DbSetup
{

public static function setup_db()
{
try {
  $connect_server = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", 'root', 'rammanoj888116' );
  $create_default = $connect_server->prepare("CREATE DATABASE manoj");
  $create_default->execute();
  $connect_server = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=manoj", 'root','rammanoj888116' );
  $connect_server->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $file = file_get_contents( 'database.sql' );
  $create_tables = $connect_server->prepare($file);
  $create_tables->execute();
  $create_tables->closeCursor();
  $file_2 = file_get_contents( 'exam_tables.sql' );
  $create_tables_2 = $connect_server->prepare($file_2);
  $create_tables_2->execute();
  echo "1";
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo "0";
  echo $e;
}
}
}
```

I am calling this function in the following manner

```
public function create_db() {
  $rv = DbSetup::setup_db();
  return $rv;
}
```

This is returning the folliwing error

> file_get_contents(database.sql): failed to open stream: No such file or >directory in **/var/www/html/portal/dbsetup/DbSetup.php** on line >**14**
>   0PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065

Comment: Have you tried using absolute paths?

Comment: I tried the folowing way in my localhost localhost/protal/dbsetup/DbSetup.php and it worked successfully. But accessing form another file or class is giving the error

Comment: You should use absolute paths rather than relative or no paths. It will look in the current directory for `database.sql`, which can change based on the page you're accessing.

Comment: Thanks, @aynber Can you predict an absolute path to the above file I used /var/www/html/portal/dbsetup/database.sql But it is not working

Comment: Can I know why the question got awarded -1? I even searched many questions at StackOverflow but unable to find a soln

Comment: If it's always going to be accessed via the browser, then use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/database.sql`. Otherwise, make sure it's the exact path to the file.

Comment: I tried it but not working. This is working form the same file but not working from the other files

Comment: Double check your error message, and make sure you're doing it for both database.sql and exam_tables.sql. If it still doesn't work, post the exact error message that you're getting after the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used

```
 $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path to my file/'
```

and this solved the problem thanks @aynber

Using the normal relative path is creating issues when the instance of the same class is being created from the other file or class. But absolute paths helped in solving it.